# Unable to get user from Azure AD using graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Hi im trying to fetch the list of users in the Azure AD. im able to generate token

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "3599",
    "expires_on": "1689943771",
    "not_before": "1689939871",
    "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "access_token": "<My token>"
}
```

Using the below api to get the details

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

Im getting response as :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-07-21T11:49:44",
            "request-id": "f6ba2d19-e8ec-4698-97cc-ad62c60931fa",
            "client-request-id": "f6ba2d19-e8ec-4698-97cc-ad62c60931fa"
        }
    }
}
```

I have added the below permission
[image: Azure Permissions]

Please let me know what im missing here.

Comment: Which authentication flow do you use?

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, client credentials flow works only with **`Application`**
> type permissions. I believe you generated token using client
> credentials flow but granted `Delegated` permissions.

To resolve the error, you need to grant `User.Read.All` **Application** type permission as below:

[image]

After granting the above permission, generate access token again. In my case, I used Postman to get token using client credentials flow like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appID
client_secret: secret 
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can verify the permission by pasting the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website:

[image]

When I used this token to call Graph API, I got list of users successfully:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

**Response:**

[image]